# Array Unique based upon first value only?

Tags: php

My array:

```
$arr = [['abc', 'a'],['xyz', 'f'],['abc', 'x']];
```

I need to remove any duplicate first values, eg. there are two abc values, above, array_unique won't work as the second value differs:

```
 $arr = array_unique($arr, SORT_REGULAR);
```

Is there a way to get only unique values based upon the first value. I cant change the above structure.

The desired output is:

```
$arr = [['abc', 'a'],['xyz', 'f']];
```

Comment: what is desired output?

Comment: Updated question with desired output.

Comment: *I need to remove any duplicate first values*. But desired output is removing the last.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[array_combine()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) & [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) can help. But it would change the order of nested arrays and will hold only last value for duplicates.

```
$arr = [['abc', 'a'],['xyz', 'f'],['abc', 'x']];
$temp = array_combine(array_column($arr, 0), $arr);
```

`array_column` is not available for older versions. (Available in **(PHP 5 >= 5.5.0, PHP 7)**)

**Output**

```
array(2) {
  ["abc"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "abc"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "x"
  }
  ["xyz"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "xyz"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "f"
  }
}
```

**array_column** will return an array with all the values from sub-arrays with `0` index.

**array_combine** will assign the sub-arrays to the values returned by `array_column`.

So as same key can not exist twice, it will overwrite the previous values with same key (for `0`) with newer values. Thus the new array will hold only the latest (last) value.

Comment: This is great, could you explain a bit more what array_column and array_combine are doing?

Comment: @panthro, Added brief description about what it is doing. Allso added the links to documentation. Hope it would help.

Comment: This was very useful, unfortunately it does change the structure of the array, anyway to get it back to the same structure after the combine? e.g. remove the key names

Comment: In that case `array_values()` would help. :)